# Reading file and directory paths from config file, how can the paths be stored in an OS independent way?

Tags: python-3.x

In my program config file I want to use different file and directory paths,  independent on the OS/cloud storage the data is stored on.
Ideally, the functionality is the same as the hard coded following code:

> import os
> model_dir=os.path.join('data','model')
> query_file = os.path.join('data','queries.json')

Obviously I can store the paths in a json config as:
"model_dir":r"data/model"
"query_file" =r"data/queries.json"

and replaces the separator dependent on the OS, but is there a more elegant way ?